# VHDL and reaction time of finite state machine?

Tags: vhdl, fsm

This is a problem I regularly bump into - hopefully someone can clarify to me the right way to think about it!

I can basically reduce my problem to this: I have a module, with input `p_in`, output `p_out` and clock `clk`. The functionality is that whenever `in` goes low - `out` should produce a high pulse with a duration of one clock period; and this "negative edge detector" is implemented as an FSM with four states: `reset`; `wt_in_lo` (wait for input low); `sample_signal` (generate high signal on output, upon detected transition to zero on input); `wt_in_hi` (wait for input high, after sample signal has been raised).

The code is included below, and the result in the `isim` simulator looks like this (*and this is behavioral simulation, so there shouldn't be any platform-specific translation influence*):

[image: fsm_react_test_annot.png]

Basically, the states do change as I expect them to - first clock posedge, the FSM recognizes `in` is low, so it transits to `sample_signal`; second clock posedge, we are in `sample_signal` state.

- However, here is my problem - I'd expect for the `out` to go high as soon as the `sample_signal` state is entered (or at least, that's what I'm trying to achieve); yet, the `out` doesn't perform the high pulse *until* the *next* state (`wt_in_hi`) is entered!

And then I usually try to code around this (i.e. setting `out` in the synchronous fsm part, which is probably a bad idea) - and end up confusing both the synthesizer and myself :)

So, in brief - is it possible that I get an `out` signal as soon as the second state is entered (and for the duration of second state); and what would be the proper way to code it?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

The code:

```
-- file: fsm_react_test_twb.vhd
---------------
-- single file testbench examples - see also;
-- http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/samples/samples.shtml

library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- NEVER call port pins "in"; "out": ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 'Syntax error near "in"'!
ENTITY negedgeDetector IS
  PORT (
    clk: IN STD_LOGIC;
    p_in : IN STD_LOGIC;
    p_out: OUT STD_LOGIC
  );
END negedgeDetector;


ARCHITECTURE structure OF negedgeDetector IS

  -- 'dummy signals' - registers
  SIGNAL w_in : STD_LOGIC := 'Z';
  SIGNAL w_out : STD_LOGIC := 'Z';

  -- fsm states
  TYPE states_ned IS -- ned: negedgeDetector
  (
    ned_reset,
    ned_wt_in_lo,       -- wait for in active low
    ned_sample_signal,  -- signal for sampling
    ned_wt_in_hi        -- wait for in active hi
  );

  -- init fsm state vars
  SIGNAL state_ned, next_state_ned: states_ned := ned_reset;

-- implementation:
BEGIN

  -- assign 'wire' / registers
  w_in <= p_in;
  p_out <= w_out;


  -- STATE MACHINES CODE =========
  sm_ned: PROCESS(state_ned, w_in) -- combinatorial process part
  BEGIN
    CASE state_ned IS

      WHEN ned_reset =>
        next_state_ned <= ned_wt_in_lo;

      WHEN ned_wt_in_lo =>
        IF w_in = '0' THEN
          next_state_ned <= ned_sample_signal;
        ELSE
          next_state_ned <= ned_wt_in_lo;
        END IF;

      WHEN ned_sample_signal =>
        next_state_ned <= ned_wt_in_hi;

      WHEN ned_wt_in_hi =>
        IF w_in = '0' THEN
          next_state_ned <= ned_wt_in_lo;
        ELSE
          next_state_ned <= ned_wt_in_hi;
        END IF;

    END CASE;
  END PROCESS sm_ned;

  out_sm_ned: PROCESS(clk) -- synchronous process part --
  BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(clk)) THEN -- returns only valid transitions;
      IF state_ned = ned_sample_signal THEN
        -- signal for sampling
        w_out <= '1';
      ELSE
        w_out <= '0';
      END IF;

      state_ned <= next_state_ned;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS out_sm_ned;

  -- END STATE MACHINES CODE =====
END structure; -- ARCHITECTURE


-- #########################

library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY fsm_react_test_twb IS
END fsm_react_test_twb;

ARCHITECTURE testbench_arch OF fsm_react_test_twb IS

  COMPONENT negedgeDetector
    PORT(
      clk:       IN STD_LOGIC;
      p_in :       IN STD_LOGIC;
      p_out:       OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
  END COMPONENT;

  -- 'wires'
  SIGNAL wCLK : std_logic := '0';

  SIGNAL wIN  : std_logic := 'Z';
  SIGNAL wOUT : std_logic := 'Z';

  -- clock parameters
  constant PERIODN : natural := 20; -- can be real := 20.0;
  constant PERIOD : time := PERIODN * 1 ns;
  constant DUTY_CYCLE : real := 0.5;
  constant OFFSET : time := 100 ns;

-- implementation of workbench
BEGIN

  -- instances of components, and their wiring (port maps)...
  UUT : negedgeDetector -- VHDL
  PORT MAP(
    clk => wCLK,
    p_in  => wIN,
    p_out => wOUT
  );

  -- PROCESSES (STATE MACHINES) CODE =========

  -- clock process for generating CLK
  clocker: PROCESS
  BEGIN

    WAIT for OFFSET;

    CLOCK_LOOP : LOOP
      wCLK <= '0';
      WAIT FOR (PERIOD - (PERIOD * DUTY_CYCLE));
      wCLK <= '1';
      WAIT FOR (PERIOD * DUTY_CYCLE);
    END LOOP CLOCK_LOOP;
  END PROCESS clocker;

  simulator: PROCESS
  BEGIN

    WAIT for OFFSET;

    WAIT for 10 ns;

    -- take 'in' low - out should detect it with a pulse
    wIN <= '0';
    WAIT for 50 ns;

    -- take 'in' high - no out
    wIN <= '1';
    WAIT for 50 ns;

    -- repeat
    wIN <= '0';
    WAIT for 50 ns;

    wIN <= '1';
    WAIT for 50 ns;

    -- hold
    WAIT;

  END PROCESS simulator;

  -- END PROCESSES (STATE MACHINES) CODE =====
END testbench_arch; -- ARCHITECTURE



-----------------------
-- call with (Xilinx ISE WebPack 13.2 tools):

-- # note: -tclbatch (isim script) _needs_ -view (*.wcfg) to run! (empty *.wcfg ok)
-- # must use isim script to run at start (and setup view)..

-- # first run:
-- echo 'vhdl work "fsm_react_test_twb.vhd"' > fsm_react_test_twb.prj
-- touch fsm_react_test_twb.wcfg
-- echo -e "wave add {/fsm_react_test_twb/wclk}\nwave add {/fsm_react_test_twb/win}\nwave add {/fsm_react_test_twb/wout}\nwave add {/fsm_react_test_twb/UUT/state_ned}\nwave add {/fsm_react_test_twb/UUT/next_state_ned}\nrun 500 ns\n" > fsm_react_test_twb.isim

-- # build sim and run:
-- fuse -o fsm_react_test_twb.exe -prj fsm_react_test_twb.prj work.fsm_react_test_twb
-- ./fsm_react_test_twb.exe -gui -tclbatch fsm_react_test_twb.isim -view fsm_react_test_twb.wcfg
```

Comment: You may want to google the word "schedule" with VHDL. You schedule the output value to be presented on the next clock (well, the next change of a signal in the sensitivity list).

Comment: Many thanks for that @AaronD.Marasco - will definitely read up on that! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking the value of `state_ned` from within a synchronous process. I.e. the output will not change before the next rising clock edge.

If you want to keep the output synchronous you would have to check the value of `next_state_ned`, e.g.:

```
out_sm_ned: PROCESS(clk) -- synchronous process part --
BEGIN
  IF (rising_edge(clk)) THEN -- returns only valid transitions;
    IF next_state_ned = ned_sample_signal THEN
      -- signal for sampling
      w_out <= '1';
    ELSE
      w_out <= '0';
    END IF;

    state_ned <= next_state_ned;
  END IF;
END PROCESS out_sm_ned;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for a state machine here. My approach would be to have a single flop and an AND gate:

```
proc_reg: process (clk,reset)
begin
  if reset = RESET_ACTIVE_LEVEL then

    q_r0 <= '0';

  elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then

    q_r0 <= p_in;

  end if;
end process proc_reg;

p_out <= '1' when p_in = '0' and q_r0 = '1' else '0';
```

If p_in is not synchronous with clk, then you can add additional register stages in front of q_r0 to clean up any meta-stability.